# how to overwrite a macro activation string in SublimeText3

Tags: sublimetext

Using SublimeText3, I want to use this macro

```
   { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+u"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/ulist.sublime-macro"} }
```

As it does not work, I find the activation is already in use in (1) :

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+u"], "command": "soft_redo" },
```

So far, so good.
To my surprise, I am correctly using my macro

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+a"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/a-link.sublime-macro"} },
```

... but this activation is also in use in (1) :

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+a"], "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "smart"} },
```

This means ... there is a mistery, or something I dont understand

Any clue ?
Thanks.

I am trying to start the console, without success - thats another question in stackoverflow of mine

(1) The "system" activation shortcuts that come up in the left window when I enter "Preferences" + "Key bindings".

On the right side window there are my keymaps from ".config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User"